# svg animation on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm trying to make a circular timeline with steps,
I am using a fullpage.js plugin that make every sections at 100% of the windows with body in overflow so actually have only 4 steps on scroll 
so the steps have to be:

```
section1 -->stroke  0%
section2 -->stroke 25%
section3 -->stroke  50%
section4 -->stroke  75%
```

In the current code I use hover for show what the effect :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#menu',
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
   });
   
  });
```

```css
 body {
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-family: 'source_sans_proextralight';
}

/********** timeline ************/
#timeline{
 position:fixed;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-top:-250px;
 margin-left:-250px;
 pointer-events: all;
 z-index:99;
}


#greycircle, #smallgreytop, #smallgreyleft, #smallgreybottom, #smallgreyright{
 stroke:rgba(204,204,204,0.4);
}
#bluecircle{
 stroke-dasharray:1510;
 stroke-dashoffset:1510;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}


#bluecircle:hover{
 stroke-dashoffset:0;
}
#smallblueleft, #smallbluebottom, #smallblueright{
 opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}

#smallbluetop:hover, #smallblueleft:hover, #smallbluebottom:hover, #smallblueright:hover{
 opacity:1;
}
 /********** section ************/
 

.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fp-scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.fp-notransition {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>



<!---------- timeline ----------->
   <div id="timeline">
   
 
   <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
<circle id="greycircle" fill="none" stroke="#727272" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024"/>

<circle id="smallgreytop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="8.643" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreyleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="488.875" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreybottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="486.691" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreyright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="10.826" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="bluecircle" fill="none" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024" transform="rotate(-90 249.85 248.065)"/>

<a xlink:href="#firstPage"><circle id="smallbluetop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="8.643" r="5.976"/></a>

<a xlink:href="#secondPage"><circle id="smallblueleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="488.875" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/></a>

<a xlink:href="#3rdPage"><circle id="smallbluebottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="486.691" r="5.976"/></a>

<a xlink:href="#4thPage"><circle id="smallblueright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="10.826" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/></a>
      </svg>

 </div>
  
  <div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section " id="don">
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="emploi">
   <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
  <p>Create Beautiful Fullscreen Scrolling Websites</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section2">
   <h2>Example</h2>
   <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section4">
   <h2>Working On Tablets</h2>
   <p>Designed to fit to different screen</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) callback `onleave(index, nextIndex, direction)`

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
      $('#bluecircle').css('stroke-dashoffset', (1510/4)*(4-(nextIndex-1)) );                  
    }
```

However, I didn't find a way to get the `anchors.length` value, this would be better than hardcoded `4`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#menu',
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                  $('#bluecircle').css('stroke-dashoffset', (1510/4)*(4-(nextIndex-1)));                  
          }
   });
  });
```

```css
body {
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-family: 'source_sans_proextralight';
}

/********** timeline ************/
#timeline{
 position:fixed;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-top:-250px;
 margin-left:-250px;
 pointer-events: all;
 z-index:99;
}


#greycircle, #smallgreytop, #smallgreyleft, #smallgreybottom, #smallgreyright{
 stroke:rgba(204,204,204,0.4);
}
#bluecircle{
 stroke-dasharray:1510;
 stroke-dashoffset:1510;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}



#smallblueleft, #smallbluebottom, #smallblueright{
 opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}

#smallbluetop:hover, #smallblueleft:hover, #smallbluebottom:hover, #smallblueright:hover{
 opacity:1;
}
 /********** section ************/
 

.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fp-scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.fp-notransition {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>



<!---------- timeline ----------->
   <div id="timeline">
   
 
   <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
<circle id="greycircle" fill="none" stroke="#727272" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024"/>

<circle id="smallgreytop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="8.643" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreyleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="488.875" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreybottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="486.691" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="smallgreyright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#A6A6A6" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="10.826" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/>

<circle id="bluecircle" fill="none" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="248.065" r="239.024" transform="rotate(-90 249.85 248.065)"/>

<a data-offset="0" xlink:href="#firstPage"><circle id="smallbluetop" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="8.643" r="5.976"/></a>

<a data-offset="1132.5" xlink:href="#secondPage"><circle id="smallblueleft" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="488.875" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/></a>

<a data-offset="755" xlink:href="#3rdPage"><circle id="smallbluebottom" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="249.85" cy="486.691" r="5.976"/></a>

<a data-offset="377.5" xlink:href="#4thPage"><circle id="smallblueright" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#2C75FF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="10.826" cy="247.667" r="5.976"/></a>
      </svg>

 </div>
  
  <div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section " id="don">
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="emploi">
   <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
  <p>Create Beautiful Fullscreen Scrolling Websites</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section2">
   <h2>Example</h2>
   <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section4">
   <h2>Working On Tablets</h2>
   <p>Designed to fit to different screen</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it s the good way but i need that the animation is working on scroll not on hover like when i scroll to the section2 the animation begin

Comment: @tib That wasn't really clear in your question, see the updated answer

Comment: Consider also using only CSS for it. fullpage.js adds a class to the body element. [Check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

Comment: it s  work good on scroll down but its ilogical on scroll top, i  have to set a remove ? or a prevIndex calcul?  actually the calcul is not making difference between scrollDown and scrollUp

Comment: @tib, no it's my bad, corrected now `(1510/4)*(4-(nextIndex-1))` instead of `(1510/4)*(4-index)`

Comment: do you know how can i do for get the small blue circle dash array appearing when scroll ?